# Highcharts Export Server: Polar Chart Ignoring Formatters in Callback

Tags: highcharts

We're currently generating a polar chart in HighCharts that renders correctly on the client-side (in the browser), and correctly applies formatters to the xAxis, yAxis, and plotOptions. Here is a jsFiddle that shows how it is rendering (correctly) in the browser: https://jsfiddle.net/cmodzelewski/38f03Lse/1/

On the server side, we are constructing a JSON payload and sending it to a node-export-server instance and returning a PNG. Based on our research, it is clear that formatters need to be included in the `callback` key of our JSON payload and passed to the server as a string, rather than in the `infile` key.

That's fine, and so we're converting our formatter functions into strings, composing them into the `options` object in our `callback` key, and then redrawing the chart at the end of our `callback` key.

This approach works great for non-polar charts, but if `polar == true` the export server returns a valid PNG from the export server, however that chart does not apply our formatter functions to the xAxis, yAxis, or plotOptions.series.

Here is the JSON payload that we are sending to a node-export-server instance:

```
{
    "callback": "function (chart) {var options = chart.options;var xAxisFormatter = function () { var extra_hrs = 0; if (this.value == 0) { extra_hrs = 12; }; return ((this.value / 0.5)/60) + extra_hrs + ':00'; };if (\"labels\" in options[\"xAxis\"]) { options[\"xAxis\"][\"labels\"][\"formatter\"] = xAxisFormatter; } else { options[\"xAxis\"][\"labels\"] = { \"formatter\": xAxisFormatter, \"style\": { \"fontSize\": \"8px\" } }; };var yAxisFormatter = function () { return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 2, '.', ',') + \"%\"; };if (\"labels\" in options[\"yAxis\"]) { options[\"yAxis\"][\"labels\"][\"formatter\"] = yAxisFormatter; } else { options[\"yAxis\"][\"labels\"] = { \"formatter\": yAxisFormatter, \"style\": { \"fontSize\": \"8px\" } };};var plotOptionsFormatter = function () { return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 2, '.', ',') + \"%\"; };options[\"plotOptions\"][\"series\"][\"dataLabels\"][\"formatter\"] = plotOptionsFormatter;chart = new Highcharts.chart(chart.container, options);chart.redraw();}",
    "infile": "{chart: {backgroundColor: \"white\", borderWidth: 0, height: 300, polar: true, width: 300}, colors: [\"#16C1F3\", \"#3C6E71\", \"#EAC435\", \"#E63946\", \"#33658A\", \"#DFD6A7\", \"#627264\", \"#86CCA5\", \"#6268B0\", \"#E8D33F\", \"#DA2C38\"], credits: {enabled: false, position: {align: \"right\", verticalAlign: \"bottom\"}, text: \"(c) Insight Industry Inc., 2017.\"}, exporting: {enabled: false}, legend: {enabled: false}, plotOptions: {column: {groupPadding: 0, pointPadding: 0}, series: {dataLabels: {}, pointInterval: 30, pointStart: 0}}, series: [{data: [{name: \"12:00am - 4:59am\", x: 0, y: 2.737994945240101}, {name: \"5:00am - 5:29am\", x: 150, y: 1.6287559674248806}, {name: \"5:30am - 5:59am\", x: 165, y: 1.6849199663016006}, {name: \"6:00am - 6:29am\", x: 180, y: 5.9112608817747825}, {name: \"6:30am - 6:59am\", x: 195, y: 11.513619769727605}, {name: \"7:00am - 7:29am\", x: 210, y: 17.98652064026959}, {name: \"7:30am - 7:59am\", x: 225, y: 17.733782645324347}, {name: \"8:00am - 8:29am\", x: 240, y: 20.190957596180848}, {name: \"8:30am - 8:59am\", x: 255, y: 7.848918843021623}, {name: \"9:00am - 9:59am\", x: 270, y: 8.438640831227183}, {name: \"10:00am - 10:59am\", x: 300, y: 3.1592249368155008}, {name: \"11:00am - 11:59am\", x: 330, y: 1.1654029766919405}], name: null, pointPlacement: \"on\", type: \"column\"}], title: {text: null}, tooltip: {style: {fontSize: \"10px\"}, valueDecimals: 1, valueSuffix: \"%\"}, xAxis: {labels: {style: {fontSize: \"10px\"}}, max: 360, min: 0, tickInterval: 30, title: {text: null}}, yAxis: {labels: {style: {fontSize: \"10px\"}}, max: 25.0, min: 0, showLastLabel: false, tickInterval: 5, title: {style: {color: \"#0A3B61\", fontSize: \"9px\", fontWeight: \"bold\"}, text: \"Workers, Aged 25+\"}}}",
    "scale": 2,
    "type": "png"
}
```

We have recreated what we (suspect) is the process that the node export server goes through, and have definitely recreated the (weird) behavior that we're seeing in this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cmodzelewski/v4gm6t9a/2/

Are we missing something blatantly obvious (which is what we suspect)? Or is there a better way of doing this to get the behavior we're looking for?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle with the suspected process, and in your callback, you are setting the axis labels in the following way:

```
options["yAxis"]["labels"]
```

This will set an object `labels` on the `yAxis` element, however, since you can have several axis in highcharts, they are indexed, and stored as such. That means you have to edit the first axis like this:

```
options["yAxis"][0]["labels"]
```

Here is a picture of the yAxis object in the **incorrect** configuration:

[image: Wrong config]

Here is a picture of the yAxis object in the **correct** configuration:

[image]

**Working example using your second fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/v4gm6t9a/4/